# Maven: How to compile only? Keep file structure intact

Tags: java, maven, azure-web-app-service

I have a regular java servlet web application with the following structure:

```
/project/
    main_sources/
        web/
            (java source code files here)
    pages/
        (jsp files here)
    WEB-INF/
        web.xml
        classes/
            (this is where all the compiled java files from main_sources go)
    css/
    scripts/
```

This all compiles fine and runs in Tomcat.

I want to compile this project in maven (keep the file structure intact).

What do I put in the POM.xml to NOT produce a WAR/JAR file? I just want it to compile the java source code into the classes folder only.

(Basically, I want to deploy it to Azure App Service and have Maven as a build pipeline task to build the project...but currently it's produce a WAR file instead).

Comment: Try `mvn compiler:compile`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you call `mvn compile`, Maven only executes the phases up to the `compile` phase, so the results will not be packaged.

As a side node: Think about refactoring your project into the standard Maven structure.

Answer (score -1):

You might be doing clean and Build project..Build generates war file.

So ,you select only compile option in maven

To compile project from maven commandline, you can use **mvn compile** command

Comment: The question is not about cleaning, but about compiling without generating a `war`.

Comment: @JFMeier.Ok thanks.I have edited my answer now.thank you for pointing out